# Apache Tomcat 8.5 Create Truststore

Tags: tomcat, encryption, tls1.2, tomcat8.5

We have a web server running Apache Tomcat 8.5. On this server we have a keystore created with a keystore password. The keystore is securing the website with TLS connection.

a.  We want to encrypt the connection between the application server and the web server. In the application installation, we need to specify: keystore (jks file), keystore password, Truststore (file), and Truststore password. I do not believe a Truststore exists, how do I see if a Truststore was created on the server? Also, if a Truststore is not created, how do I create a Truststore?

b.  If I create a Truststore, will the link to the web application remain working as usual on the Tomcat server as this is already only using a Keystore? Are any updates needed to the server.xml file? The server.xml file is updated with the Keystore information. We only want to create a Truststore to secure the connection between the servers.

I am expecting to secure the connection between the application server and the web server by TLS connection. Currently, this has a keystore and may also need a Truststore .

Comment: Looks like a question about server administration and setup, rather than programming (see [help/on-topic]). If not that, there are several questions at once, and not quite a clear [mcve]. I'd recommend to move it over to serverfault.com, or edit it to be more on topic here.

Comment: I'm unsure of the network architecture being described here. TCP networking is described in terms of clients that initiate connections and servers that listen for and accept connections from clients. But you have two entities that are described as 'servers'. So which is the TLS server and which is the TLS client? As for a truststore, every JDK install includes a truststore in a file called `cacerts` which is consulted by default for TLS certificate verification. If your server is using a certificate signed by a well known CA then you should already have what you need without doing anything.

Comment: If you want a higher level of security that the default you can setup something called certificate pinning which takes a little bit of extra work. Note that pinning is more complicated and very intolerant of mistakes. There is something called 'pinning suicide' which happens in certain misconfigurations. Some environments like Android make pinning easier than others.